# How Youtube developers debug with the crash message?

Tags: debugging, encryption, youtube, stack-trace

My youtube crashed today and i was shown this wall of strings. Is this an encrypted string for which they will decrypt to get a human-readable stack trace etc?

[image]

Comment: Could be anything, really. Stack trace is a good guess. Maybe it contains more information than that. Maybe it contains no information and is just there to make you feel like something is happening.

Comment: you give us a screenshot and not the text. I cannot decrypt screenshots.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you send them the text they can de-crypt and get information on what happened and why your YouTube crashed (hence why they don't want screenshots). It's encrypted (this is speculation) either so they can protect your private information or they have data they don't want you to see in the crash reports.